# Cycles doesn't Render Particle Scale Changes... Is this a Bug?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, transforms

When I create a particle system in Cycles, It looks fine in the viewport and in Eevee, but the second I render it in Cycles, it's like it forgets its scaling Texture ramp.

**Below is the texure Ramp Im using to influence the Scale and the settings for the particle itself:**

[image: The scale influence driven using the Texture Color Ramp (White to Light Grey)]

[image]

**Viewport with Cycles:**

[image]

**Render with Cycles:**

[image]

As you can probably see the scale of the flame particle is very obviously bigger in the render.
In the full animation it doesnt scale at all, What's weird is the second I switch the Physics Type from None to any other type, the scaling suddenly works.

Im honestly at a loss here so I've resorted to asking for help. :c

Edited for Bump,

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't show us any setting you made, thx.

Comment: Please make your workflow and objectives _very_ explicit, so we don't have to deduce them.. "I've set the particles to scale using  a texture influence. I want them to .. XXX" And so on. That would make it much easier for folks to help you.

Comment: The problem with your question is, you don't show anything about how you implemented this scaling. Scaling can be done in different ways, I don't know what a "Texture ramp" is in this case. And "switch the Type" is quite vague too, there are types to switch in different areas of Blender (especially when you only mention the "None" option but not what else there is to choose from).

Answer (score 0):

When you render as object the scale is set here

[image]

as a multiplier of the base object scale.

I don't know if particle size behaves differently between the two engines, but it's where I would look.

Comment: That shouldnt effect the Scale Ramps ability though. I did set it to 1 just to test this theory, however, and it had no effect. Same issue with scale not taking effect.

I am using an over time scale ramp btw. So it sould decrease in size the longer its alive

Comment: I guess I don't know where these settings are coming from, so I can't help

Comment: They are located in the Particle and the Texture side bars. Click on an object, go to the sidebar and click the one called particles (Looks like 4 dots connected by lines), click the "+" button and now you have the settings there.